# vim - search and replace a function

Tags: vim, replace

I want to replace a function in the following way.

```
Old function :
old_func(a,b,c)

New function :
new_func(b,a,c)
```

How to replace old_func with new_func and also take care of arguments(in vim)?

Comment: Refactoring is hard in the general case especially when you have nested functions call in your arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vim supports backreference (`\1` for the first captured group and `\2` for the second):

```
%s/\<old_func(\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),/new_func(\2,\1,/g
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer macro's since that requires less brain energy. You record 1 edit and play that back as much as you want.

First search for old_func:

```
/old_func<ENTER>
```

Start recording a macro in register q:

```
qq
```

Go to the next occurence of new_func and change old into new :

```
n      # Next occurence
ct_    # change until '_'
new    # 'new'
ESC    # back to normal mode
```

Go inside the bracket and switch the arguments

```
f(l    # find '(' and step 1 to the right
d2l    # delete two characters ( 'a' and ',' )
l      # move 1 place to the right
p      # paste deleted characters
```

Stop recording macro:

```
q
```

Playback macro

```
@q     # once
500@q  # 500 times, it will stop if it can't find anymore occurences of old_func
```

### UPDATE

If your arguments are not called a and b than you can switch the arguments like this:

```
f(l    # find '(' and step 1 to the right
df,    # delete the characters including the comma
f,     # move to the next comma
p      # paste deleted characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting this done in a single pass would be difficult. If you *always* have the same arguments `a` and `b`, then you could probably write a regex (or macro, as was already suggested) for it, but I'm assuming that's not the case and you have different expressions in different places.

My solution would rely on my [sideways.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim) plugin. Basically, first replace `old_func` with `new_func`, then go around all usages and use the plugin to swap the two arguments.

For convenience, I'd also use another plugin of mine, [writable_search](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/writable_search.vim) that puts all search results in a single buffer. And if you have them in a single buffer, it would be easy to automate the argument swapping as well, with a macro.

If the `:SidewaysRight` command is mapped to `s>`, then the process would be:

- Search for the function in the buffer with `/old_func(`
- Start recording a macro with `qq`
- Change the function name with, say, `cwnew_func<esc>`
- Go to the first argument with a `f(l`
- Perform the sideways motion, `s>`
- Go to the next match with `n`
- Stop the macro with a `q`

Now, executing `@q` will go to the next match and perform the action.

Comment: His new_func will end up as old_func ;)